# hi I'M not getting the textfeild druing module development

Tags: forms

```
$form['companydetails']['contact name']=array(
  '#type' => 'textfeild',
  '#title' => t('Contact name'),
);
```

this is my code but I'm not getting textfeild infront f contactname attribute....im getting blank page.....please help me out

Comment: It is impossible to guess what's wrong studying such narrow segment of your code.

Comment: I aggree with @molot but I see a typo in your code 'textfeild' instead of 'textfield'. That might be the issue?

Comment: Yes. It is the typo. And did you return the $form in your main module file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be more than one problem with this. Off the top of my head (with my knowledge of custom modules) it could be one of the following:

1. Incorrect spelling of 'textfield' in the #type parameter. (if the code is matched in your module file).
2. Is 'company details' a parent of 'contact_name' e.g. a fieldset?
3. Are you returning $form at the end of the module_hook function?

Maybe if you could provide the whole code surrounding the module_hook() function I could help a bit better?

Comment: 1.i have changed textfeild to textfield but nochanges

Comment: 2.yes company details is the feild set

Comment: 3.yes im returning the form at the end

Comment: thanks got it ,actually i forgot to add '#' in type feild